# Magento change pricing displayed on frontend

Tags: php, magento

I need to change the pricing displayed on the frontend based on the product Attribute Set.

We're storing pricing based on `width in metres x 0.10 metre`, but I need to calculate and display the price on the frontend based on metre squared.

So what I attempted to do was in price.phtml:

```
        <?php
        $attributeSetModel = Mage::getModel("eav/entity_attribute_set");
        $attributeSetModel->load($_product->getAttributeSetId());
        if($_product->isConfigurable()) {
            if ($attributeSetModel->getAttributeSetName() == 'SETNAME') {
                $_finalPrice = (($_price * 10) / 4);
            }
        }
        ?>
```

This does change the price, but I'm dividing by 4 when I actually need to divide by whatever metre width the product is.

In order to do this I attempted to use this piece of code to get the Attribute Value for width:

```
Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($_product->getId(), 'width', Mage::app()->getStore())
```

However, this doesn't work for configurable products.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call a get method on the product object or the loaded attributes. Maybe $_product->getWidth()?

Comment: This doesn't work within the price.phtml file. I'm looking at creating an observer now, hopefully I'll be able to figure it out this way.